# C# Encoding a text string with line breaks

Tags: c#, encoding, response

I have a string I am writing to the outputstream of the response. After I save this document and open it in Notepad++ or WordPad I get nicely formatted line breaks where they are intended, but when I open this document with the regular old Windows Notepad, I get one long text string with □ (square like symbols) where the line breaks should be.

Has anyone had any experience with this?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Yes - it means you're using `\n` as the line break instead of `\r\n`. Notepad only understands the latter.

(Note that `Environment.NewLine` suggested by others is fine if you want the platform default - but if you're serving from Mono and definitely want `\r\n`, you should specify it explicitly.)

Comment: Thanks Jon. "serving from Mono"?  What's that?

Comment: As in, "Deploying a server using Mono on Linux, and asking that server to serve the data." Mono is a cross-platform implementation of .NET - see http://mono-project.com

Answer (score 24):

Use [Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) for line breaks.

Answer (score 14):

Try this :

```
string myStr = ...
myStr = myStr.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine)
```

Comment: if input string contains both \n and \r\n such operation will break it

Comment: "I get one long text string with [] square looking symbols where the line breaks should be."
Looks like it's not the case.

Comment: @Guillaume: It's not the case *this time*, but there's no reason why a file can't contain two or more different kinds of line separator--I see it in web pages all the time.  When you're normalizing newlines you should always match all three kinds: `Regex.Replace(@"\n|\r\n?", "\r\n")`

Comment: When you are noemalizing newlines from a non standard source ok.
But when you KNOW you will ONLY have '\n' you don't need a regex...

Answer (score 2):

Try ***\n\n*** , it will work! :)

```
public async Task AjudaAsync(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result){
       await context.PostAsync("How can I help you? \n\n 1.To Schedule \n\n 2.Consult");
       context.Wait(MessageReceived);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the connection from your strange task to the topic.

Answer (score 2):

Also:

```
string s = $"first line{Environment.NewLine}second line";
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before it's better to use `Environment.NewLine`. 
`\n` represents the newline character and is commonly used for line breaks in Unix-like systems (such as Linux and macOS) and in many programming languages.

`Environment.NewLine` is a platform-specific string that represents the newline sequence for the current operating system. **It automatically adapts to the newline convention used on the platform** where the code is running. On Windows, `Environment.NewLine` is equivalent to `\r\n`, while on Unix-like systems, it is equivalent to `\n`.