# New Line in StringWriter

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext, stringwriter

I need a new line in my `StringWriter`. It is just not happening. Please help.

```
    stringWrite.WriteLine(Header);
    stringWrite.Write("\n ========================================================");
```

`Header` is a string.

I tried `stringWrite.WriteLine`. That isn't working either.

[image]

Comment: Where are you writing to? What are you using to read the output data (file, another console, app, etc)? That should work completely fine in any case (whether it's Mono, or .NET WIndows)

Comment: To tell the truth, it is working. I have hust tested it in Console Apllication.

Comment: Have you tried using `Environment.NewLine`? But as Dan said, this should work...

Comment: @Dan I'm writing this into a PDF.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad That's not working either.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev I uploaded a screenshot. Pls check.

Comment: @divinediu how you wrote it works for me

Comment: @chrfin`stringWrite.WriteLine(Header); stringWrite.Write(Environment.NewLine); stringWrite.WriteLine(" ========================================================");` isnt working either

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187121/c-sharp-encoding-a-text-string-with-line-breaks

Comment: stringWrite.WriteLine("\r\n========================================================");

Comment: If you're writing to raw PDF, try using a line break "<br>", but really this all depends on what PDF library you are using.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Tried in a different browser. Any idea what the problem may be?

Comment: \r\n should work. its weird that its not working in your case

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Tried both `\r\n` and `environment.newline`. Not working. PDF looks very ugly.

Comment: Here is a similar issue @divinediu:
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/507423

Comment: clean solution and rebuild it, may be old build is running again and again

Comment: @Dan PERFECT! Never imagined that a <br> tag would be detected. Thanks a lot!! Please answer my question so I can mark your solution as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, since you're writing to PDF files, they require the use of the `<br>` tags (line break in html) instead of the normal \n format for new lines.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing \r, in Windows a newline is composded of carriage return (\r) and new line (\n) so to create a newline you must add \r\n

Comment: Didn't work for me as I'm using a PDF. @Dan Provided me with the right answer. Thanks.